# Render a field multiple times in Twig and Symfony

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I need two inputs so that the user can choose from

**Controller**

```
$etud = new Etudiant();
$form=$this->createFormBuilder($etud)
    ->add('filierechoisit',EntityType::class,array('class'=>'inscriptionBundle\Entity\filieres', 'choice_label'=>'libelle_filiere'))
    ->add('filierechoisit',EntityType::class,array('class'=>'inscriptionBundle\Entity\filieres', 'choice_label'=>'libelle_filiere'))->getForm();
if ($form->isValid()) {
    // ... maybe do some form processing, like saving the Task and Tag objects
}

return $this->render('inscriptionBundle:Default:authentification.html.twig', array(
    'modif' => $form->createView(),
));
```

How can I do it?

Comment: 2 fields with the same name? How do you see that to work?

Comment: i know it doesn't i just ran out of options :p , any idea how can i do this ?

Comment: Surely that's a collection type. Have a read of the form documentation in detail: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

Comment: "any idea how can i do this" --- how you can do *what*? You have not explained the problem, you just posted a snippet of code that makes very little sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost sure you want a [ChoiceType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html)/[EntityType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) field with [multiple](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#multiple) and [expanded](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#expanded) options as `true`. 
It should be something like this:

```
$form->add('filierechoisit', EntityType::class, array(
    # query choices from this entity
    'class' => 'inscriptionBundle\Entity\filieres',
    # use the filieres.libelle_filiere property as the visible option string
    'choice_label' => 'libelle_filiere',
    # used to render a select box, check boxes or radios
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the form processing and form rendering. If you want user to choose which way he enters data - you do not want to process this data in two different ways until these are two independent fields.

You should just have one

```
->add('filierechoisit',EntityType::class,array('class'=>'inscriptionBundle\Entity\filieres', 'choice_label'=>'libelle_filiere'))
```

call to add field processing and left all rendering for the front-end side. You could use some JS, or API there, or in simple case, just override Twig template for that field

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

You could render your own widget for your form here, allowing user to do some html stuff to change input.

Currently, making two `add` with identical names call just makes the second one override the first.